# WordPress JS Loading Issues with Bootstrap and Popper

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, popper.js

There seems to be something wacky going on with scripts as they load causing issues. I have this:

```
function fyxt_custom_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    //load order is important (from website jquery, popper, bootstrap)
    wp_register_script('prefix_bootstrap', '//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery' ),'',true );
    wp_enqueue_script('prefix_bootstrap');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'fyxt_custom_scripts' );
```

I am getting the following console error:

Uncaught TypeError: Bootstrap's tooltips require Popper.js (https://popper.js.org/)

So I add in the following to WordPress getting popper in there.

```
    function fyxt_custom_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
        //popper for bootstrap
        wp_register_script( 'popper','https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js', array( 'jquery' ),'',true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'popper' );
        //load order is important (from website jquery, popper, bootstrap)
        wp_register_script('prefix_bootstrap', '//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery' ),'',true );
        wp_enqueue_script('prefix_bootstrap');
    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'fyxt_custom_scripts' );
```

Once that is in it loads popper in. But now I am getting another error. Any idea why?

```
tooltip.js:559 Uncaught TypeError: this.element.getAttribute is not a function
    at i.t._fixTitle (tooltip.js:559)
    at i.t._setListeners (tooltip.js:554)
    at new i (tooltip.js:142)
    at i.t._enter (tooltip.js:576)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (tooltip.js:528)
    at HTMLDocument.handle (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:3)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:3)
    at HTMLDocument.r.handle (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:3)
```

So it seems like tooltip is recognized but says it needs popper. But then it gets it and tooltip errors out. What is going on here?

I tried a couple solutions and nothing is working. I think this has to do with load order/dependencies. Here is the loading script in full.

```
function fyxt_custom_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-custom', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ )  . '../css/fyxt-theme-2/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-custom', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ )  . '../css/fyxt-theme-2/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css' );   

    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-core' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-tabs' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-button' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-accordion' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-slider' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-core' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-widget' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-progressbar' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-sortable' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-autocomplete' ); //for tags, use later for generators (powers, effects, etc)

    wp_enqueue_script( 'tabs-script', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '../js/tabs.js', array('jquery-ui-core', 'jquery-ui-accordion', 'jquery-ui-tabs') );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'tags-script', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '../js/tagmanager-master/tagmanager.js', array(), '', false );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'tags-custom', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '../js/tagmanager-master/tagmanager.css' );

    //plupload
    wp_enqueue_script( 'plupload-full', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '../js/plupload.full.min.js', array(), '', false );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'plupload-scripts', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '../js/jquery.ui.plupload/jquery.ui.plupload.min.js', array(), '', false );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'plupload-css', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '../js/jquery.ui.plupload/css/jquery.ui.plupload.css' );

    //popper for bootstrap
    wp_register_script( 'popper','https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js', array( 'jquery' ),'', false );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'popper' );

    //bootstrap
    wp_register_style('prefix_bootstrap', '//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('prefix_bootstrap');

    //load order is important (from website jquery, popper, bootstrap)
    wp_register_script('prefix_bootstrap', '//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'popper' ),'', false );
    wp_enqueue_script('prefix_bootstrap');

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'fyxt_custom_scripts' );
```

If the 'tabs-script' is included I get the error, jquery buttons are all broken. Tabs and accordions work.

```
tooltip.js:568 Uncaught TypeError: this.element.getAttribute is not a function
    at i.t._fixTitle (tooltip.js:568)
    at i.t._setListeners (tooltip.js:563)
    at new i (tooltip.js:140)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (tooltip.js:767)
    at Function.each (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
    at a.fn.init.each (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
    at a.fn.init.i._jQueryInterface [as tooltip] (tooltip.js:758)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (tabs.js?ver=ec6af3c620057499034adb106af5aae1:10)
    at i (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
    at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
```

If I comment out the 'tabs-script' I get the jquery buttons to work but then it breaks tabs and accordion.

```
jquery.ui.plupload.min.js?ver=ec6af3c620057499034adb106af5aae1:1 Uncaught TypeError: i.widget is not a function
    at jquery.ui.plupload.min.js?ver=ec6af3c620057499034adb106af5aae1:1
    at jquery.ui.plupload.min.js?ver=ec6af3c620057499034adb106af5aae1:1
```

I am not to familiar with load orders and dependencies so advice here would be great. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: try to change the version of jQuery, I mean remove the existing jquery provided by wordpress and load it from CDN. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/download/#bootstrapcdn

Comment: I updated to the newest and it did not fix it, still getting errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that PLUpload was the one causing the issues. I tried many different configurations and load orders and it always seemed to break with plupload. I have decided not to use it and instead go with another similar plugin, Dropzone. PLupload has not been updated in a few years so think it is better to go with a more recently updated/modern style anyway. Thank you all for your tips and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is respect the URLs that Bootstrap provide to me (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/):

1. https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css
2. https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js
3. https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js

Then in my function I just include the references that I need:

```
function fyxt_custom_scripts(){
    wp_register_style(('prefix_bootstrap', 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), '4.4.1', 'all');


    wp_register_script('popper', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js', array( 'jquery' ),'1.16.0', true );


    wp_register_script('prefix_bootstrap', 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery', 'popper' ),'4.4.1', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'fyxt_custom_scripts' );
```

I follow Bootstrap recomendations and place the scripts call in the footer.
After that make sure that you have the calls to the functions 
`<?php get_header() ?>` and `<?php get_footer() ?>` between the `<head>...</head>` HTML tags and just before `</body>` HTML tag respectivelly in your theme.

Answer (score -1):

You should move all the JS scripts into the footer. I hope it would help you out. Please have a look below:

```js
function fyxt_custom_scripts() {
}

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'fyxt_custom_scripts' );
```

Comment: They are still causing errors. I think the load order or something is messing these up. I added the dependency in where I know they were but not sure if I need to add more.

Comment: You should also disable each of the js files from where it is calling in function.php or footer.php then unable one by one and check which js are conflicting. It might be helpful.